# Create a RESTful Web Service proxy to existing RESTful Web Service

Tags: rest, apache-camel, jax-rs, cxf, jbossfuse

I'm working now in Camel route and i want to create a proxy Rest WS to call an existting Rest WS. I had created it for SOAP WS.
Is their anyone who know the steps to create this route.
PS : Im working with Json(Gson library) and In JBoss Fuse Envirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create http proxy route, based on **jetty**, **http**, **http4** and so on:

```
<route id="serviceProxy">
    <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8181/service/?disableStreamCache=true&amp;matchOnUriPrefix=true&amp;continuationTimeout=900000&amp;httpClient.timeout=120000"/>
    <to uri="jetty:http://{{app-server.host}}:{{app-server.http.port}}/service/?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false&amp;continuationTimeout=120000&amp;httpClient.timeout=900000"/>
</route>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I have a question: how i make this adress http://0.0.0.0:8181/ variable, i mean it must take the host and  port of the deploying server automatically

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means any address of your host on which this route is deployed (localhost, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.XXX.XXX). Of course you can specify a specific IP, or specify property placeholder.  Same with the port. You can specify, hardcode your http server (JBoss Fuse ) port, or use property placeholder (like {{app-server.http.port}}), for externalizing configuration.